# ¿Como extraer un dato en especifico de un .txt de Pyhton

Tags: python-3.x

En mi archivo tengo una lista con diferentes datos por ejemplo:

```
Food: carne, Amount: 621, Time: 33, ID:1
Food: fideos, Amount: 383, Time: 41, ID:2
```

Con estos datos puedo calcular el `amount total`,pero si elimino un línea de estas es decir una comida no se como tomar el amount de esta misma para restárselo al total, ya que no estaría mas.